# Access is denied when running an async function twice that writes to local storage

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I have a C# project with a service reference against a web service.

I have the following code, first to trigger a method at the service request:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     App.service.getFileCompleted += service_getFileCompleted;
     App.service.getFileAsync(App.user, App.document);
 }
```

And the `service_getFileCompleted` is supposed to retrieve a `byte[]`, put it into a file and then open that file with the default application:

```
 async void service_getFileCompleted(object sender, BackendReference.getFileCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
            string tmp = "temp." + e.Result.type;

            StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile localFile = await local.CreateFileAsync(tmp, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            using (Stream writeStream = await localFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                writeStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                await writeStream.WriteAsync(e.Result.fileData, 0, e.Result.fileData.Length);
            }

            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(localFile);

        }
 }
```

First time the apps starts, and the button is triggered it works like a charm. However, when pressing the button the second time the row

```
Stream writeStream = await localFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()
```

casts an `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.

More exactly:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.d__5.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.d__5.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   at archive.DocumentDetail.d__0.MoveNext()}  System.Exception {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}

Why is this so?

Thanks

Comment: Well you're launching the file - presumably the application still has the file open, and you're trying to overwrite it...

Comment: As Jon say, most probably the file is in use the second time you try to push the button. This can be very simple to fix if you use some variable, like DateTime.Now.Ticks for the file name. This way every time you click on a button, the name is different so no UnauthorizedAccessException is launched.